# Is 各式各样 Taiwanese version of 各种各样?

Tags: usage, difference, idioms

I know that 各式各样 = 各种各样, but is one Taiwanese version of the other one? What I mean is: is one more frequently used in China and the other is more frequently in Taiwan?

Comment: Both phrases are not entirely the same at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 各式各样 VS 各种各样

To this mainland speaker, they are not entirely the same.  Both are common and we can't say one is more common than the other.

各式各样 is about the differences in 样式, while 各种各样 the differences in 种类.  In other words, with 各式各样 we see all types of things **within one category**. With
各种各样 we see different **kinds/categories** of things.

Colloquially, sometimes they might be used interchangeably.  However, native speakers do feel the nuance between the two.

Answer (score 4):

One crude method for testing Taiwanse vs. Chinese usage is by running a verbatim

> site:.cn
> site:.tw

Google query.

---

Here are some results:

各式各样 site:.tw about 761’000 results
各式各样 site:.cn about 24’100’000 results

but maybe Google isn't good with sc vs. tc:

各式各樣 site:.tw about 12’300’000 results
各式各樣 site:.cn about 315’000 results

There doesn't seem to be much of a difference in usage amounts overall.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, that's a great hint! However, I'm a statistician, so I will correct your way of research. First of all, as you mentioned, we should use simplified Chinese to search Chinese results and traditional Chinese to search Taiwanese results. The second thing which you didn't do, but is important, is comparing one expression to the other! Results:

Comment: geshigeyang - 19kk Taiwan, 27kk China; gezhonggeyang - 12kk Taiwan, 72kk China. So the conclusion is that in China it is way more common to hear 各种各样. In Taiwan it's a little more common to hear 各式各样. By "hear", of course, I mean "see on the internet" :P

Comment: I am sure 各式各样 is more common in Hong Kong

Comment: I once asked a question about which is the standard version among 長年累月，常年累月，經年累月，積年累月. The answer is '長年累月' is the most common one based on internet search results, But semantically, 積年累月 makes the most sense because 積累 is a compound word, but 經累, 長累, and 常累 are not. In this case, popularity may not equal correctness. I heard all four and I myself use 長年累月 as most Hong Kong Chinese do

Comment: I forgot. 窮年累月 is on the list too